# ¿Como puedo hacer que aparezcan los datos seleccionados de mi select al momento de mandar a imprimir?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, print

Hola tengo un problema con mi código, le agregue un botón de imprimir y este imprime una parte especifica del código solo que al visualizar la pantalla de impresión no salen los datos seleccionados de mi form (son puros select) si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho, gracias.
Aquí les adjunto mi código..
......................................................
Hola tengo un problema con mi código, le agregue un botón de imprimir y este imprime una parte especifica del código solo que al visualizar la pantalla de impresión no salen los datos seleccionados de mi form (son puros select) si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería mucho, gracias.
Aquí les adjunto mi código..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      .container h2{
        text-align: center;
      }
      .container p{
        text-align: center;
      }
      .texto_total {
        align-items: center;
      }
      .botones_enviar {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .botones_borrar_imprimir {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .boton_imprimir {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:800;
        font-size:14px;
        color:#ffffff;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        padding-left:30px;
        padding-right:30px;
        background-color:#E20F7E;
        border-color: #E20F7E;
      }
      .centrar {
      text-align: center;
      }
      select { width: 400px; text-align-last:center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="imp1"> 

    <center>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Cotización Libretas</h2>
          <p> Cotiza y envianos tu presupuesto.</p>
          <b>
          <hr>
          </b>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div> <br><br>

    <center>

    <form action="mailto:david_swag_v@hotmail.com" method="post" name="sumar" id ="contacto" enctype="text/plain">

        <b>
        <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1"> Opciónes de impresión </p>
        </b>

        <label>Tipo</label> <br>
        <select name="Tipo" class="Tipo">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="100">SIN suaje/pestaña (22.5 x 29.2 cm)</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <label>Cantidad</label> <br>
        <select name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="20">25</option>
            <option value="40">50</option>
            <option value="80">100</option>
            <option value="120">200</option>
            <option value="160">300</option>
            <option value="300">500</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <label>Impresión</label> <br>
        <select name="Impresion" class="Impresion">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="50">4/0 (Color solo frente)</option>
            <option value="100">4/4 (Color frente y vuelta)</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <label>Tipo de papel</label> <br>
        <select name="Tipodepapel" class="Tipodepapel">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="200">Coché 300 g</option>
            <option value="300">Cartulina sulfatada 12 pts 1 cara</option>
        </select>
        <br><br><br>
        
        <b>
        <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1">  Terminados </p>
        </b>

        <label>Plastificado frente y vuelta</label> <br>
        <select name="Plastificadofrenteyvuelta" class="Plastificadofrenteyvuelta">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="150">Delgado brillante (BOPP)</option>
            <option value="300">Delgado mate (BOPP)</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <label>Esquinas redondeadas (con datos de contacto hacia arriba)</label> <br>
        <select name="Esquinasredondeadas" class="Esquinasredondeadas">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="0">Ninguna</option>
            <option value="80">4</option>
        </select>
        <br> <br><br>

    <div class="texto_total">
        <b>
        <label>Total</label> <br>
        </b>
        <input class="centrar" type="text" name="total"> <br> <br>
    </div>

  </center>

  </div>
    
    <div class="botones_enviar">
        <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" class="email" placeholder="Dirección e-mail"> <br> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Cotización</button> <br> <br>
    </div>

    <div class="botones_borrar_imprimir">
        <div class="clear"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-8"> 
                <input type="Reset" value="Borrar Datos">
        </div> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <button class="boton_imprimir" type="button" onclick="javascript:imprim1(imp1);">Imprimir Cotización</button>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    </form>

  </center>

    <script>
      function imprim1(imp1){
      var printContents = document.getElementById('imp1').innerHTML;
              w = window.open();
              w.document.write(printContents);
              w.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
              w.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
          w.print();
          w.close();
              return true;}
    </script>

    <script>
        var numero3 = 0, numero1 = 0, numero2 = 0, numero4 = 0, numero5 = 0, numero6 = 0;
    caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;

    $(".Tipo").change(function() {
      numero1 = parseFloat(caja["Tipo"].value);
      mostrar();
    });
    
    $(".Cantidad").change(function() {
      numero2 = parseFloat(caja["Cantidad"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".Impresion").change(function() {
      numero3 = parseFloat(caja["Impresion"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".Tipodepapel").change(function() {
      numero4 = parseFloat(caja["Tipodepapel"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".Plastificadofrenteyvuelta").change(function() {
      numero5 = parseFloat(caja["Plastificadofrenteyvuelta"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".Esquinasredondeadas").change(function() {
      numero6 = parseFloat(caja["Esquinasredondeadas"].value);
      mostrar();
    });


    function mostrar() {
        if (numero1 >= 0 && numero2 >= 0 && numero3 >= 0 && numero4 >= 0 && numero5 >= 0 && numero6 >= 0) {
            var resultado = 0;
            resultado = (numero1 + numero2 + numero3 + numero4 + numero5 + numero6);
            caja["total"].value = (resultado);  
        }
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola con mostrar en pantalla te refieres a un `alert(mensaje)` o en pantalla crear un div vacio que vaya cambiando con el resultado, es decir tienes un div vacio y con JS cambias el contenido por el resultado?

Comment: tienes que obtener el valor del select; lo consigues con: (documentacion)[https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/]

Comment: `$( "#myselect" ).val(); ` para el valor y  `$( "#myselect option:selected" ).text(); ` el texto de lo que seleccionaste.